# TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null at JQLite.(anonymous function) at at Scope.parent.$get.Scope.$broadcast

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

In my project I am using  angular version 1.4.6 and angular ui router version 2.15

Note : I just updated angular from 1.4.3.

Whenever I change states on my page I get below error.
Code is same I just  updated angular version.

Error
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
    at JQLite.(anonymous function) (http://localhost:8001/jspm_packages/npm/angular@1.4.6/angular.js:1718:22)
    at Scope.parent.$get.Scope.$broadcast (http://localhost:8001/jspm_packages/npm/angular@1.4.6/angular.js:7701:32)
    at Scope.parent.$get.Scope.$destroy (http://localhost:8001/jspm_packages/npm/angular@1.4.6/angular.js:7535:18)
    at cleanupLastView (http://localhost:8001/jspm_packages/github/angular-ui/ui-router@0.2.15/angular-ui-router.js:3939:26)
    at http://localhost:8001/jspm_packages/github/angular-ui/ui-router@0.2.15/angular-ui-router.js:3972:13
    at publicLinkFn (http://localhost:8001/jspm_packages/npm/angular@1.4.6/angular.js:2976:15)
    at updateView (http://localhost:8001/jspm_packages/github/angular-ui/ui-router@0.2.15/angular-ui-router.js:3962:23)
    at http://localhost:8001/jspm_packages/github/angular-ui/ui-router@0.2.15/angular-ui-router.js:3924:11
    at Scope.parent.$get.Scope.$broadcast (http://localhost:8001/jspm_packages/npm/angular@1.4.6/angular.js:7701:32)
    at $state.transitionTo.$state.transition.resolved.then.$state.transition (http://localhost:8001/jspm_packages/github/angular-ui/ui-

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error. Turned out to be an issue in angular-material. Are you using it? upgrading to 0.11.0-master-1a99821 fixed it for me.

Comment: I am using - v0.11.0-master-1a0fc6b